# Lucene wildcard queries

Tags: java, lucene, wildcard

I have this question relating to Lucene.

I have a form and I get a text from it and I want to perform a full text search in several fields. Suppose I get from the input the text "textToLook".

I have a Lucene Analyzer with several filters. One of them is lowerCaseFilter, so when I create the index, words will be lowercased.

Imagine I want to search into two fields field1 and field2 so the lucene query would be something like this (note that 'textToLook' now is 'texttolook'):

```
field1: texttolook* field2:texttolook*
```

In my class I have something like this to create the query. I works when there is no wildcard.

```
String text = "textToLook";
String[] fields = {"field1", "field2"};
//analyser is the same as the one used for indexing
Analyzer analyzer = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("customAnalyzer");
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryTextoLibre = parser.parse(text);
```

With this code the query would be:

```
field1: texttolook field2:texttolook
```

but If I set text to "textToLook*" I get

```
field1: textToLook* field2:textToLook*
```

which won't find correctly as the indexes are in lowercase.

I have read in lucene website this:

> " Wildcard, Prefix, and Fuzzy queries
>   are not passed through the Analyzer,
>   which is the component that performs
>   operations such as stemming and
>   lowercasing"

My problem cannot be solved by setting the behaviour case insensitive cause my analyzer has other fields which for examples remove some suffixes of words.

I think I can solve the problem by getting how the text would be after going through the filters of my analyzer, then I could add the "*" and then I could build the Query with MultiFieldQueryParser. So in this example I woud get "textToLower" and after being passed to to these filters I could get "texttolower". After this I could make "textotolower*".

But, is there any way to get the value of my text variable after going through all my analyzer's filters? How can I get all the filters of my analyzer? Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use QueryParser.setLowercaseExpandedTerms(true)?

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Are_Wildcard.2C_Prefix.2C_and_Fuzzy_queries_case_sensitive.3F

** EDIT **

Okay, I understand your issue now.  You actually want the wildcarded term to be stemmed before it's run through the wildcard query.

You can subclass QueryParser and override

```
protected Query getWildcardQuery(String field, String termStr) throws ParseException
```

to run termStr through the analyzer before the WildcardQuery is constructed.

This might not be what the user expects, though. There's a reason why they've decided not to run wildcarded terms through the analyzer, per the faq:

> The reason for skipping the Analyzer
>   is that if you were searching for
>   "dogs*" you would not want "dogs" 
>   first stemmed to "dog", since that
>   would then match "dog*", which is not
>   the intended query.

Comment: I had already seen this, but it doesn't solve the problem. I have more filters than the lowercase one. As I mentioned one of them eliminates suffixes of words, so if I index for example "changeable" it would be index as "change", so if I would search for "changes" in the query should get the root of the word ("change") and look for "change*" and these words would match.