# WildcardQuery not returning correct result

Tags: java, search, lucene, wildcard

I have created an index using some data. Now I am using WildcardQuery to search this data. The documents indexed have a field name `Product Code` against which I am searching.

Below is the code that I am using for creating the query and searching:

`Term productCodeTerm = new Term("Product Code", "*"+searchText+"*");`

`query = new WildcardQuery(productCodeTerm);`

`searcher.search(query, 100);`

The searchText variable contains the search string that is used to search the index. In case when `searchString` is 'jf', I get the following result:

```
JF32358
JF5215
JF2592
```

Now, when I try to search using `25, or f2 or f3` or anything else other than using only `j,f,jf`, then the query has no hits.

I am not able to understand why it is happening. Can someone help me understand the reason the search is behaving in this way?

Comment: case sensitive issue? related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432486/lucene-wildcard-queries

Comment: Case is not the problem here. Numeric parts are always same, they are not in capital case or lower case.

Comment: but you said 'f2', 'f3' not just '2' or '3'.

Comment: I have mentioned `25`, which contains only numeric digits.

Comment: ok, sorry, missed that. was thinking it was coz of case only :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What analyzer did you use at indexing time? Given your examples, you should make sure that your analyzer:

- does lowercasing,
- does not remove digits,
- does not split at boundaries between letters and digits.

Comment: I have used StopAnalyzer for indexing. It does lowercasing, does not remove digits. Though I am not sure about the 3 point. But even if it will split at boundaries between letters and digits, then when I search using only digits (32 for example), then it should work. Shouldn't it?

Comment: I found the issue. It was due to the third point mentioned by you. `StopAnalyzer` uses `LetterTokenizer` for creating tokens which will break the string at the boundary between letters and digits. Thanks.

Comment: But if it will do it that way, will it not store the numeric literals at all or will create separate token for the numeric value (ex 32358) or will create separate tokens for all numeric values (ex 3,2,3,5,8)?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "that way"? If I understand correcly what you are doing, you could just use a WhitespaceTokenizer filtered by a LowercasingFilter and a StopFilter.

Comment: By that way I mean splitting at non-letters.

Answer (score 0):

In the lucene FAQ page it says :

> Leading wildcards (e.g. *ook) are not supported by the QueryParser by
>   default. As of Lucene 2.1, they can be enabled by calling
>   QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true ). Note that this can be an
>   expensive operation: it requires scanning the list of tokens in the
>   index in its entirety to look for those that match the pattern.

For more information check [here.](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F)

Comment: I am not using a QueryParser to parse the query. Secondly, if the leading wildcard is not supported, then when I search using the string *f*, I should not get any results, but that is not the case here. The problem only comes, when I either use only integers, or character + integers.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for trying to help. :)